# Error in finding difference of days in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *  
from feedback f 
where datediff(day, feedback.submitOn, getdate()) < 7
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The multi-part identifier "feedback.submitOn" could not be bound.

`submitOn` is of type `Date`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a table alias:

```
select *
from feedback f 
where datediff(day, f.submitOn, getdate()) < 7
```

You have given the reference to `feedback` the name `f`.  You need to use it.

I would recommend that you use date arithmetic, rather than the difference between dates.  You probably want:

```
where f.submitOn < dateadd(day, 7, convert(date, getdate())
```

This gives you everything from more than 7 days ago.  This is better because it helps the optimizer and allows the query to take advantage of indexes and partitions.

Comment: yes it worked it thanks i tried it without alias as well works fine